# C floating point number 0x1.fp3

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, c99

From an article:

*"GNU CC recognizes floating-point numbers written not only in the usual decimal notation, such as 1.55e1, but **also numbers such as 0x1.fp3 written in hexadecimal format**. In that format the 0x hex introducer and the p or P exponent field are mandatory. The exponent is a decimal number that indicates the power of 2 by which the significand part will be multiplied. **Thus 0x1.f is 1 15/16, p3 multiplies it by 8**, and the value of 0x1.fp3 is the same as 1.55e1. "*

It seems to say 0x1.fp3 is evaluated as = (1 + 15/16 ) * 2^3

Where the 15/16 came from ?

Comment: The online reference for the hexadecimal floating-point format is http://www.exploringbinary.com/hexadecimal-floating-point-constants/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it's hexadecimal format, then `0.1` means `1/16`, `0.2` means `2/16`, ... `0.a` means `10/16`, ..., `0.f` means `15/16`.